# get all the data from all the cells when merge the cells in excel?

Tags: excel

when merges the cells data in excel, the default state is the last cell  merged only get the left data.

eg: `A2: Hello  B2:world  C2:test`  when i merge `A2,B2,C2`. the data i get will be `Hello`. if i want to get `Helloworldtest`

now i want to get all the data in the cells and **display the data in the original cell(the merged cell)**. how do i do ? thank you。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=a2&b2&c2
```

in cell `d2` (for example) to consolidate all of the data together for the first 3 columns of the row.

As mentioned in a comment on the other answer, the documentation for the Concatenate function that NirMH suggested is [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-HP005209020.aspx).  The following function call will produce the same results as the ampersand method in my answer `=CONCATENTATE(a2,b2,c2)`

Comment: if i want to make the data displays in the merged cell, how do i do?

Comment: @zhuanzhou what do you mean by displayed?  The concatenated data is a string and will be shown.

Comment: @zhuanzhou Tell me what you put in each of the cells, what the output is, and what you expect the output to be

Comment: eg: A2: Hello B2:world C2:test when i merge A2,B2,C2. then displays the cell data in  ABC cell. not a new cell.

Comment: @zhuanzhou Okay. Yes, I just tried it.  It will have to be placed in a new cell, as otherwise if you tried to put it back into a2, you would get a circular reference.  You could of course, put it into a temporary cell and copy and paste it back.

Comment: when i merged the A2,B2,C2 Cell, it popped up a window. which says the selected region containing multi numbers value, it only remains the left data

Comment: @zhu Yes, the underlying logic probably can't deal with a circular reference either.  It's just going to have to go into a new cell, I don't think there's any way around it.

Comment: @zhu Did you find a way to make it work within the constraints of your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the `CONCATENATE` function? what is the issue with using it?

Comment: i am sorry,i am a new learner of excel, i don't know how to use the CONCATENATE function. could you tell me how to use it. thank you.

Comment: @zhuanzhou The documentation for Concatenate is [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-HP005209020.aspx).  It's essentially the same as the ampersand method in my answer `=CONCATENTATE(a2,b2,c2)` would give the same result.  It would still need to be in a new cell, though.